# Execute a command on a list of strings in Bash

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm trying to find all C# interfaces from a given directory. I tried doing this command:

```
find . -type f | xargs basename | grep ^I
```

but `basename` is giving back an error since I'm sending it a list of strings, not a string itself. How do I get the output of `basename` executed over all the strings piped to it?

Comment: What about `... | xargs -i basename "{}" | ...`?

Comment: @higuaro Thanks! (You might want to put that as the answer, by the way.)

Comment: Is there some problem with `echo I*`? (Perhaps you really need a recursive listing, or maybe you have folders whose names start with `I`?)

Comment: @rici Yes, to clarify I wanted a recursive list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `xargs` for this. You can use:

```
find . -type f -name 'I*' -exec basename '{}' ';'
```

If you are using GNU find, you don't need `basename` either:

```
find . -type f -name 'I*' -printf %f\\n
```

Here, `%f` is the GNU find printf format for "filename with all but the last component removed". There are many other possible format codes; see `man find` for details.

Comment: Nice; these ran pretty fast compared to piping it through `xargs`.

Comment: @JamesKo: The second one should be fastest, if your find supports it, since it doesn't require firing up any new process.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs -i` should solve the problem:

```
find . -type f | xargs -i basename "{}" | grep ^I
```